# R arules package: Merge rules subsets into an unique rules set

Tags: r, merge, arules

I'm getting association rules with the `arules` package in R. I've got a lot of rules and I'm trying to remove redundant ones. The procedure I'm following in order to get it is based on a matrix and sum what rules are subsets of other rules. If I apply this procedure (let's call it `remove.redundant.rules()`) to the whole rules set, R is not allowed to store an amazingly big matrix, so I've decided to remove redundant rules by little batches and then apply the general procedure to the resultant set. (That's the plan).

When I do the batches I do something like this:

```
for(batch in seq(1,length(rules),by=batch_size)){
  rules_batch<-rules[batch:((batch+batch_size)-1)]
  pruned_batch<-remove.redundant.rules(rules_batch)
}
```

I get `length(rules)/batch_size` subsets of rules. Each `pruned_batch` is from type `rules` of `arules` package. My plan is to do something like this:

```
whole.rules<-arules::rules() #That's just pseudocode
for(batch in seq(1,length(rules),by=batch.size)){
    rules.batch<-rules[batch:((batch+batch.size)-1)]
    pruned.batch<-remove.redundant.rules(rules.batch)
    whole.rules<-rbind(whole.rules,pruned.batch) #That's just pseudocode
}
whole.rules<-remove.redundant.rules(whole.rules)
```

Now, `whole.rules` should be from type `rules` of `arules` package too. So, Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Sorry I can't get a reproducible example, but it would mean a lot of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Michael Hahsler response (partial solution) I've developed the final solution. That is:

```
whole.rules<-whole.rules[!is.redundant(whole.rules)]
whole.rules<-remove.redundant.rules(whole.rules)
```

Remove redundant rules with `is.redundant()` and so if I have A => B and B => A I keep only one depending of classical quality measures (implemented in `remove.redundant.rules`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep *unique rule* (as in the title), or do you want to remove *redundant rules*? For unique rules use `unique` and for removing redundant rules look at the examples for `is.redundant`. Both should work for reasonably large rule sets.